# Is there interest in a separate SE site specific for woodworking?

Tags: discussion, scope

I enjoy the Q&A-format for researching information quite a lot and I noticed that there wasn't one available specific to woodworking.  There are many woodworkers here on Home Improvement, but the overall scope of this site is a little different and I think many woodworking questions would be off-topic.  The issue of whether woodworking questions are on-topic was [was raised](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/are-woodworking-questions-in-scope) and the determination seemed to be that at least some woodworking questions (like those about crafting small objects) would be off-topic.  Furthermore, I can imagine questions on building musical instruments, wooden boats, species identification, or preparing felled and salvaged trees being closed.

Seeing as the entirety of woodworking does not fit in with diy.SE, I wonder if,
among the woodworkers here, there is interest in a separate site?  Personally, I feel that there is a *lot* of woodworking expertise out there and the umbrella of Home Improvement misses the mark in attracting them.  A dedicated site might have better results.

I have recently created a [proposal for woodworking.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61927/woodworking?referrer=KiPtL-stfbZEcOlY9VldUw2) to gauge interest.  We will see where that goes, but I wonder what the opinion is here?

Comment: Word of advice: if you replace the link to the proposal page on Area 51 with the "Share this" link from that page, you'll get rep for everyone that follows the proposal through that link. There's also a cumulative effect where those people's rep gets added to your own during commitment which effectively doubles it up.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been several woodworking proposals on Area 51 over the years. I know I've followed at least three of them, and there may have been more that I didn't notice because I don't always visit [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) regularly. I do know that other frequent visitors to this site followed some of those earlier woodworking proposals, so there is some interest.

From what I've seen, these proposals typically gather some followers, then languish until they're automatically closed and deleted. Some time later, someone else will propose it again, and the cycle repeats.

This may sound discouraging, but consider that the same thing happened with several proposals for a pets Q&A site, and once the most recent proposal got into commitment, it took off quite quickly, and now seems to be a high-energy [beta site](http://pets.stackexchange.com).

A way to promote the proposal would be through the [community ads](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/739/22), which show up on the main site's home page.